# How do I diagnose a possible regression in the Java package?

Tags: xorg, java

Yesterday, after installing the daily software updates, I experienced high CPU usage in a Java application that has been working fine until then. Java was among the updated packages. From `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2015-10-29  07:18:28
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.108'
Install: libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.16+dfsg-2), lksctp-tools:amd64 (1.0.16+dfsg-2, automatic)
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common:amd64 (3.1.1+15.10.20150720-0ubuntu1~0vivid1, 3.1.1+15.10.20151018-0ubuntu1~0vivid1), python-apport:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), ubuntu-sdk-qmake-extras:amd64 (3.1.1+15.10.20150720-0ubuntu1~0vivid1, 3.1.1+15.10.20151018-0ubuntu1~0vivid1), libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), php5-mysql:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), php5-common:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), php5-curl:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), php5-dev:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), python-problem-report:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:amd64 (3.1.1+15.10.20150720-0ubuntu1~0vivid1, 3.1.1+15.10.20151018-0ubuntu1~0vivid1), php5-readline:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), php5:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1), shotwell-common:amd64 (0.20.2-0ubuntu3, 0.20.2-0ubuntu4), shotwell:amd64 (0.20.2-0ubuntu3, 0.20.2-0ubuntu4), openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1), ntp:amd64 (4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6, 4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6.2), apport-kde:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), php5-cli:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1), openjdk-7-source:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), apport:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), php-pear:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), libaudiofile1:amd64 (0.3.6-2, 0.3.6-2ubuntu0.15.04.1), icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1), openjdk-7-doc:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1), python3-apport:amd64 (2.17.2-0ubuntu1.5, 2.17.2-0ubuntu1.7), php5-gd:amd64 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.3, 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4), ntpdate:amd64 (4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6, 4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu6.2)
End-Date: 2015-10-29  07:19:15
```

While the application is running, both `java` and `Xorg` use more than 50% CPU. This is causing general slowness in the application, and I'm sure it was not the case in the past.

The application is actually a (swing-based) game. Although it's open source, I suppose it's not fit for a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I can't use it to file a bug report. Also, I don't know *where* I could report.

My question is: how can I find out what is wrong, so that I can report a bug somewhere (where?) and help fixing the issue?

I did take [a thread dump](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13101754/), but I don't know what to do with it, since no thread is actually blocked.

My environment:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.15.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

$ uname -a
Linux pif 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:04:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

I had a look with VisualVM, and noticed that the CPU usage reported there (10%) is much smaller than the one reported by `top` (45%):
[image]

Another thing that I tried was to run it with Java 8. In this case, the game runs fine, and the CPU usage reported by `top` is around 20-22% for each of: `java`, `Xorg` and `compiz`.

Comment: Can you post a thread dump ?

Comment: This is the thread dump: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13101754/ (I also just included the link in the question).

Comment: A thread dump only tells you what is running, and what state the threads are in. Ideally, you want to use a profiler to measure what the threads are actually doing, and for how long. VisualVM is a basic profiler that might be present if you have a JDK on this system. JProfile is  another commercial application. You should also see if this is a heap or garbage collection issue. The CPU might be high because the system is paging hard because of memory pressure.

Comment: I had a look with VisualVM, and noticed that the CPU usage reported there (10%) is much smaller than the one reported by `top` (45%). Screenshot in the question.

Comment: How the system reports these numbers is going to necessarily be different than other methods, but I think you are looking at the wrong process in VisualVM. When I see "starter" in a class I would look elsewhere for the actual app -- this looks like a launcher class that launches the real class, and the system may be reporting on this and some other work at the same time. The system is reporting on the whole java process, which VisualVM is looking at discrete activity within that process.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean and I would expect the same thing. But in this case, `Starter` is just the name of the main class; there's nothing else AFAIK. You can see in the screenshot, it's pid `6694` in both `top` and `jvisualvm`.

Comment: The problem is that this PID really means nothing to Java. It is present as a convenience only. That is, this single instance of a class is not the entirety of what the PID is from the system POV. Try sampling the entire JVM instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have VisualVM running as a profiler, which is the right tool for this job, the idea is to collect enough data to find out where the hot spots are.

The system is reporting on the entire Java process. Profiling tools are a way to look at the work within that process (and, indeed, a "process" makes no sense to a profiler. It is looking at a number of threads and classloaders within a single JVM instance.)

Since you want to collect information that you can use to report back to the OpenJDK project (or, probably, the authors of the game) you might want to experiment with the "Sample" capabilities. The idea is that we want a snapshot of activity over time, probably a number of snapshots, so we can see what parts of the JVM were hottest during the identified problem we see from the point-of-view of the system.

This way we can see if it is methods related to the game code, or the native or non-native code within the JVM itself.

(I will add that profiling running apps is a bit of a black art. My advice is to make sure you are really looking at the JVM instance you think you are, and spending some time with the interface to figure out what you are collecting. Performance investigations are often more about understanding what you are trying to do more than what information you actually get; it's about making sure you are asking the right questions.)